# AngularJS app loading and processing JSON data once for multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm working on an Angular app, where I'm running into mostly the same problem as in this post:
[AngularJS App: Load data from JSON once and use it in several controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784714/angularjs-app-load-data-from-json-once-and-use-it-in-several-controllers)

I've got a factory that reads a JSON file, and returns the whole data object. Each controller, then, uses this factory (as a service?) to *obtain* the data, but then each controller has to pick it apart on its own. The JSON has to be searched and processed to get the relevant payload like, `$scope.currentArray = data.someThing.allItems[i];` etc, and I obviously don't want to repeat this code in all the controllers.

Seems to me I can either find some way to *share* the data, after, say, MainController (the "first one") has finished working it, **or I can add some new module "between" the controllers and the factory.** This new module -- let's call it `myProcessService`? -- would then be the one getting the data object from the factory, and do all the processing there... once and for all. Then, each controller would only deal with `myProcessService` to (somehow) get the ready-formatted variables and arrays etc onto their respective scopes (yes, this is Angular 1).

If I try to give an example of how I'm doing this so far, maybe someone can help me with the necessary improvements? And, I am aware that it is a good idea to begin using the Angular 2 patterns already today, but please understand that I am first trying to get some grasp of how A1 works, before delving into A2 :)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);


app.factory('getDataFile', ['$http', function($http) {
    function getStream(pid) {
        return $http.get("data/" + pid + ".json")
            .success(function(data) {
                    console.info("Found data for pid " + pid);
                    return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                    console.error("Cant find data for pid " + pid);
                    return err;
            });
    }
    return {getStream: getStream};
}]);


app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'getDataFile', 
    function($scope, getDataFile) {     
        getDataFile.getStream('10101011').success(function(data) {

            // process "data" into what's relevant:
            var i = getRelevantIndexForToday(new Date());
            $scope.myVar = data.someField; 
            $scope.currentArray = data.someThing.allItems[i]; 
            // etc... you get the drift
        }
    }]);

app.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', 'getDataFile', 
    function($scope, getDataFile) {     
        getDataFile.getStream('10101011').success(function(data) {

            // process "data" into what's relevant:
            var i = getRelevantIndexForToday(new Date());
            $scope.myVar = data.someField; 
            $scope.currentArray = data.someThing.allItems[i]; 
            // etc... you get the drift
        }
    }]);
```

### Edit:

My ngRouter is set up something like this. They fill the `ng-view` div in my index.html. However -- and maybe this is frowned upon? -- I've *also* got a "MainController" which sits directly in the index.html `body` tag, such that I can show some data (from the back end) in the header part of the single page application.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/:id/work/:page_id', {
    controller: 'AssetController',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/work.html'
  })
  .when('/:id/work/', {
    redirectTo: '/:id/work/1'
  })
  .when('/:id/', {
    controller: 'DashController',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/dashboard.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

});
```

and index.html is a lot like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">

        <h1>Welcome, {{username}}</h1>

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So you want to be able to load the data once...and only work on local version across the app...is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Load once, and let all controllers/views use same data!

Comment: ... Use, and update! same data :) But I guess two-way is implicit with angular?

Comment: Seems like you are on the right track. Answers in linked question should do what you need. As for transforming the data differently in different views, that can be done in factory or controller. Most like to keep controllers as thin as possible

Comment: Well, I did look at the answers there, but I don't see how and where those examples actually work the data object before just returning it. The question is also different, in exactly that respect; I need to work the Json, not just "get" it... But, maybe I'm just not understanding the answers properly :-)

Comment: well the main feature of those is storing the data locally. You can then use whatever method you need to get that data to another controller ... but always pulling from the local data store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another helper function in your factory, that returns the required object that you want to share between controllers.

```
app.factory('getDataFile', ['$http', function($http) {
    function getStream(pid) {
        return $http.get("data/" + pid + ".json")
            .success(function(data) {
                    console.info("Found data for pid " + pid);
                    return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                    console.error("Cant find data for pid " + pid);
                    return err;
            });
    }

    function getCurrent(pid) {
        return getStream(pid).then(function() {
                var i = getRelevantIndexForToday(new Date());

            return  {
                myVar: data.someField,
                currentArray: data.someThing.allItems[i];
            };
        });
    }

    return {
        getStream: getStream,
      getCurrent: getCurrent
    };
}]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'getDataFile', 
    function($scope, getDataFile) {     
        getDataFile.getCurrent('10101011').success(function(data) {
            $scope.myVar = data.myVar; 
            $scope.currentArray = data.currentArray; 
            // etc... you get the drift
        }
    }]);

app.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', 'current', 
    function($scope, current) {     
        .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.myVar = data.myVar; 
            $scope.currentArray = data.currentArray;  
        }
    }]);
```

**Suggestion:**

Also I suggest you to use `resolve` which allows you to pass data to your controller from your route.

**Route:**

```
.when('/:id/work', {
    controller: 'AssetController',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/work.html',
     resolve: {
        // you are injecting current variable in the controller with the data. You can inject this to each of your controller. you dont need to add the whole function in your next route. Just use current
        current: function(getDataFile){
           return getDataFile.getCurrent('10101011');
        }
  })
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'current', 
    function($scope, current) {     
        $scope.myVar = current.myVar; 
        $scope.currentArray = current.currentArray;
    }]);

app.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', 'current', 
    function($scope, current) {     

        $scope.myVar = current.myVar; 
        $scope.currentArray = current.currentArray;  

    }]);
```

Now that you have

Comment: That looks like just what I need, thanks!  So, it can all be contained within one and same module (factory)? Excellent!

Comment: You can create separate factories for relevant api calls. In this case you can have all your functions related to stream in this factory. I will also update the question with suggestion on how to use resolve which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving an answer in line with my use of deprecated methods `success` and `error`, Subash. However, I had some problems with the code in your answer, and I got some help on #angularjs, so I thought I should post the updated code here.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('getDataFile', ['$http', function($http) {
    function getStream(pid) {
        // here, using placeholder data URL, just to get some data:
        return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(function(result) {
                    console.info("Found data for pid " + pid);
                    return result.data;
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                    console.error("Cant find data for pid " + pid);
                    return err;
            });
    }

    function getCurrent(pid) {
        return getStream(pid).then(function(data) {
            var i = 1;  // test
            console.log("myVar = ", data[i].name);
            return  {
                myVar: data[i].name
            };
        });
    }

    return {
        getStream: getStream,
      getCurrent: getCurrent
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'getDataFile', 
    function($scope, getDataFile) {     
        $scope.name = "j";
        getDataFile.getCurrent('10101011').then(function(user) {
            $scope.myVar = user.myVar;

            console.log("controller. myVar = ", user);
            // etc... you get the drift
        });
    }]);
```